# Limit of a sequence of functions in the Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

Let $\mathbb{D} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be the unit disk and consider the Dirichlet problem of the Laplace equation $\Delta u = 0$ in $\mathbb{D}$ with $u = 0$ on $\partial \mathbb{D}$. Then we know that the solution to this problem is $u \equiv 0$ and that it minimizes the Dirichlet energy defined as
\begin{gather}
E[u] := \int_{\mathbb{D}} | \nabla u|^2
\end{gather}

Construct a sequence of functions $\{u_k\} \subset C(\overline{\mathbb{D}})$ satisfying the following conditions

1. $u_k$ is piecewise smooth and $u_k|_{\mathbb{\partial D}}=0$ $\forall\ k \in \mathbb{N}$
2. $E[u_k] \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$
3. $u_k$ diverges as $k \to \infty$ in a set that is dense in $\mathbb{D}$

**Then show that** $u_k \to 0$ in the *Sobolev space* $H^1(\mathbb{D})$

---

Ok, I have constructed a sequence satisfying the aforementioned properties but I cannot understand how can $u_k \to 0$ in $H^1(\mathbb{D})$. I understand that the Sobolev space is equiped with the norm
\begin{align}
\|u\|_{H^1} &:= \Big( \int_{\mathbb{D}} (|\nabla u |^2 + |u|^2)\Big)^{1/2}\\ \|u\|^2_{H^1} &= \|\nabla u\|^2_{L^2(\mathbb{D})} + \|u\|^2_{L^2(\mathbb{D})}
\end{align}
and that by Property 2 we have $\|\nabla u_k\|_{L^2(\mathbb{D})} \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$ but still $u_k$ diverges in a dense subset of $\mathbb{D}$ (Property 3) and thus we should have $\|u_k\|_{L^2(\mathbb{D})} \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$ which means that $u \notin H^1(\mathbb{D})$.

Could you please explain me that? Also, where am I wrong in the above considerations?

Thanks!

---

**Update**
After @daw's answer I want to clarify that I constructed a sequence diverging in an *uncountable* dense subset. Does anything on the above declaration of the problem forbids me to do that? Or is it softly implied that the subset must be countable?

Comment: Imho there is nothing in the question that requires the countability of the subset, where divergence occurs. Could you post your sequence as a separate answer? Would be interesting to see.

Comment: @daw I am not posting the sequence because I figured out that in fact the energy diverged. Instead I formulated a sequence based on your answer, with logarithmic singularities, that will work. I think that taking $\{q_k\}$ as the Cantor set (instead of $\mathbb{D} \cap \mathbb{Q}$) with the same sequence $u_k$, proves the claim for an uncountable dense subset while ensuring measure zero to prove the convergence in $H^1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dense subset still can have measure zero (think of points with rational coordinates), so your conclusion: property (3) implies $\|u_k\|_{L^2}\to\infty$ is not valid. Also it would contradict the Poincare inequality.

The construction of $u_k$ would be something like
$$
u_k = \frac1{k^2} \sum_{i=1}^k \phi_i,
$$
where $\phi_k \in H^1(\Omega)\setminus L^\infty(\Omega)$, $\|\phi_k\|_{H^1}=1$ with singularity at some $q_k$,
where $(q_k)$ is dense in $\mathbb D$.

In order to get an approximation by continuous functions, we can approximate $\phi_k$ by $\phi_{k,n}$ with $\phi_{k,n}\to \phi_k$ and $\|\phi_{k,n}\|_{H^1}\le 2$. Then set 
$$
u_n = \frac1{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \phi_{i,n},
$$

Comment: I think that this series might not converge. You might want to replace $1/k$ with $1/k^2$?

Comment: @daw Thanks you are absolutely right, I was seeing this now, that I can have a countable dense subset. It is that I have constructed the sequence diverging on an uncountable dense subset. So this cannot hold for an uncountable dense subset, right?

Comment: @daw I haven't accepted the question only because it's still not clear to me. I have slightly updated the question, could you clarify this last point to me?

Comment: @daw Btw, I just noticed, why you excluded the function space of essentially bounded functions from $H^1$ to pick $\phi_k$? We need $u_k$ to be continuous and thus $\phi_k(q_k)$ must go to infinity for $k\to\infty$ and not for any $k$. What do I miss?